# Execute workflow from JavaScript in CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, workflow, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm attempting to execute a workflow for records selected in a view, via a ribbon button.  I have a working example using the 'legacy' services for CRM 4 compatibility:

```
function invokeWorkflow(workflowId, entityId) {
    var request =
        '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"' +
        '               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"' +
        '               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' +
           GenerateAuthenticationHeader() +
        '  <soap:Body>' +
        '    <Execute xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices">' +
        '      <Request xsi:type="ExecuteWorkflowRequest">' +
        '        <EntityId>' + entityId + '</EntityId>' +
        '        <WorkflowId>' + workflowId + '</WorkflowId>' +
        '      </Request>' +
        '    </Execute>' +
        '  </soap:Body>' +
        '</soap:Envelope>';

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/MSCRMservices/2007/crmservice.asmx', false);

    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices/Execute');

    xhr.send(request);
}
```

However, I want to write this using CRM 2011 services to increase maintainability for future releases.  Here is what I've tried so far, but this does not work - the return code of the call is HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error).

```
function invokeWorkflow(workflowId, entityId) {
    var request =
        '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"' +
        '               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"' +
        '               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' +
        '  <soap:Body>' +
        '    <Execute xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services">' +
        '      <Request xsi:type="ExecuteWorkflowRequest">' +
        '        <EntityId>' + entityId + '</EntityId>' +
        '        <WorkflowId>' + workflowId + '</WorkflowId>' +
        '      </Request>' +
        '    </Execute>' +
        '  </soap:Body>' +
        '</soap:Envelope>';

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/web', true);

    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/xml, text/xml, */*');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/IOrganizationService/Execute');

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () { alert(xhr.status); };
    xhr.send(request);
}
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with the second script?  I've tried Googling this as best I can but every example I find which claims to be for CRM 2011 is in fact just using the CRM 4 compatibility services (as in the first example).  I've based the second example from a sample in the CRM 2011 SDK, although this doesn't include an example of the ExecuteWorkflowRequest object so it's best-guess only.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an application named **SOAPLogger** in the CRM sdk folder \samplecode\cs\client\soaplogger that generates requests in javascript for specific actions.

Below, you can find the http request for "ExecuteWorkflow" (just change the value for `EntityIdValue` and `WorkflowIdValue`).

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <Execute xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <request i:type="b:ExecuteWorkflowRequest" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2011/Contracts">
        <a:Parameters xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
          <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <c:key>EntityId</c:key>
            <c:value i:type="d:guid" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">EntityIdValue</c:value>
          </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
          <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <c:key>WorkflowId</c:key>
            <c:value i:type="d:guid" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">WorkflowIdValue</c:value>
          </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
        </a:Parameters>
        <a:RequestId i:nil="true" />
        <a:RequestName>ExecuteWorkflow</a:RequestName>
      </request>
    </Execute>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The construction of `XMLHttpRequest` is corect, so try changing the `soapEnvelope`.